# How can I write a range of /16 IP addresses in a single expression?

Tags: ip

I'd like to ban this range of Chinese IP addresses in nginx:

```
 '223.64.0.0 - 223.117.255.255'
```

I know how to ban each of `/16` range like:

```
deny 223.64.0.0/16;
```

But it will take many lines to include the whole `223.64 - 223.117` range. Is there a shorthand notation to do so in one line?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[ipcalc](http://jodies.de/ipcalc) (`ipcalc` package on Debian) can help you *deaggregate* a range into a number of matching [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation)s:

```
$ ipcalc -r 223.64.0.0 - 223.117.255.255
deaggregate 223.64.0.0 - 223.117.255.255
223.64.0.0/11
223.96.0.0/12
223.112.0.0/14
223.116.0.0/15
```

Same with [that other ipcalc](https://gitlab.com/ipcalc/ipcalc) (`ipcalc-ng` package and command name on Debian):

```
$ ipcalc-ng -d '223.64.0.0 - 223.117.255.255'
[Deaggregated networks]
Network:        223.64.0.0/11
Network:        223.96.0.0/12
Network:        223.112.0.0/14
Network:        223.116.0.0/15
```

That one has more options to vary the output format:

```
$ ipcalc-ng --no-decorate -d '223.64.0.0 - 223.117.255.255'
223.64.0.0/11
223.96.0.0/12
223.112.0.0/14
223.116.0.0/15
```

Including json which gives endless possibilities of reformatting if combined with tools like `jq`:

```
$ ipcalc-ng -j -d '223.64.0.0 - 223.117.255.255' |
    jq -r '.DEAGGREGATEDNETWORK[]|"deny " + . + ";"'
deny 223.64.0.0/11;
deny 223.96.0.0/12;
deny 223.112.0.0/14;
deny 223.116.0.0/15;
```

```
$ ipcalc-ng -j -d '223.64.0.0 - 223.117.255.255' |
   jq -r '"deny " + (.DEAGGREGATEDNETWORK|join(" ")) + ";"'
deny 223.64.0.0/11 223.96.0.0/12 223.112.0.0/14 223.116.0.0/15;
```

Comment: To complete the answer, the term for the technique is [supernetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernetwork). Thanks for the new tool - I didn't know `ipcalc` and `ipcalc-ng` exist :-)

Comment: Adding more completeness, the `ipcalc` provided with RHEL/CentOS 7 and earlier is neither of the above, nor is it capable of working out the deaggregation. The `ipcalc` provided with RHEL 8 and its derivatives is the same as Debian's `ipcalc-ng`, but it's an earlier version that does not support the `-d` option.

Comment: Does RHEL 8 have Python? You'll get the same result using the [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.summarize_address_range) module, e.g. `python3 -c "import sys, ipaddress; first, last = map(ipaddress.ip_address, sys.argv[1:3]); print(*ipaddress.summarize_address_range(first, last), sep='\n')" 223.64.0.0 223.117.255.255`.

Comment: @user1686, you should make an answer out of that.

Answer (score 7):

`@StéphaneChazelas`' answer is excellent.  In the event that the OP or a future reader might prefer to **not** have the results aggregated -- such as when each /16 is to be blocked, but in a granular fashion that would allow for future UNblocking of one or more individual /16s, I often use either `jot` or `seq` to generate the range of IPs necessary.

Sometimes one knows only the CIDR of the network to be blocked.  Assume we want to block 10.24.0.0/14, but at a granularity of individual /16s.

```
# jot -w 10.%d.0.0/16 4 24
10.24.0.0/16
10.25.0.0/16
10.26.0.0/16
10.27.0.0/16
```

In the above example, the constant `4` appears because there are 4 /16s in a /14, or put another way, 2**(16-14) = 2**2 = 4.

To block 10.0.64.0/19 as a series of /24s:

```
# jot -w 10.0.%d.0/24 32 64
10.0.64.0/24
10.0.65.0/24
10.0.66.0/24
...
10.0.92.0/24
10.0.93.0/24
10.0.94.0/24
10.0.95.0/24
```

Again, the constant 32 is used because there are 32 /24s in a /19.  Or to calculate it another way, 2**(24-19) == 2**5 == 32.

Other times, the network range is not specified in CIDR syntax, either because it doesn't fall on strict CIDR boundaries, or simply because the author of the source document elected not to use CIDR notation.  `seq` is sometimes easier to adapt to this situation.

To block 10.100.0.0 through 10.109.255.255:

```
# seq -f '10.%g.0.0/16' 100 109
10.100.0.0/16
10.101.0.0/16
10.102.0.0/16
10.103.0.0/16
10.104.0.0/16
10.105.0.0/16
10.106.0.0/16
10.107.0.0/16
10.108.0.0/16
10.109.0.0/16
```

Obviously, just outputting these IP ranges to stdout isn't going to block anything by themselves.  It is assumed that the user will either `vi` these into a config file, or perhaps pipe them to a shell script or other system command that will perform the necessary work.  If the required command syntax is sufficiently simple, `seq` or `jot` can be used to generate shell input directly:

```
# seq -f 'ipfw add 560 deny ip from 10.%g.0.0/16 to any' 100 109
ipfw add 560 deny ip from 10.100.0.0/16 to any
ipfw add 560 deny ip from 10.101.0.0/16 to any
ipfw add 560 deny ip from 10.102.0.0/16 to any
ipfw add 560 deny ip from 10.103.0.0/16 to any
ipfw add 560 deny ip from 10.104.0.0/16 to any
ipfw add 560 deny ip from 10.105.0.0/16 to any
ipfw add 560 deny ip from 10.106.0.0/16 to any
ipfw add 560 deny ip from 10.107.0.0/16 to any
ipfw add 560 deny ip from 10.108.0.0/16 to any
ipfw add 560 deny ip from 10.109.0.0/16 to any
```

After inspecting those commands for accuracy, the output of `seq` could be piped to `sh` and executed.

This solution is provided just to show that as with many UNIX tasks, there are basic building blocks that can accomplish this task in the event that granularity is preferred (or indeed, required) over aggregation.

Comment: Or just `printf 'deny %s;\n' 223.{64..117}.0.0/16` with any shell supporting zsh's `{x..y}` operator. Can be extended to `printf 'deny %s;\n' 10.{10..12}.{0..255}.0/24`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Handy if one knows y.  Given only a CIDR spec, one only knows x and n, so `jot -w '...' n x` can often be quicker to figure out.